# Grafana: Panel with time of last result

Tags: monitoring, grafana

I have an elasticsearch instance that receives logs from multiple backup routines. I'd like to query ES for these logs from Grafana and set up a panel that shows the last time for the different backups. Ideally I would also like to be able to show this in color if the time is longer than a certain threshold.

Basically the idea is to have a display that shows, for instance, green if a certain backup has been completed in the last 24 hours, and red if it hasn't.

How would I do this in Grafana with ES as the datasource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exact implementation depends on the used panel.

Example for singlestat: write ES query and then select `Stat`: `Time of last point`, you may need to select suitable unit/format:

[image]

Unfortunately, Grafana doesn't understand thresholds in your requested time format (older than 24 hours). You will need to return it as metric (for example as age of last backup in seconds) = you will need to write query for that. That means, that you will have 2 stats to show (last time + age), so you won't be able to use singlestat. Probably table panel will be better - you can use thresholding based on the age metric there.

Comment: I'm assuming when you say that I'll need to write a query to get the age of the document, I'd need to use a scripted field to get the age... Something like `System.currentTimeMillis() - doc['@timestamp'].date.getMillis()`. But how do you use a scripted field query in Grafana? I know that I can put a script in for a metric but that's only for a numeric field and @timestamp isn't available.

Comment: Script example: https://community.grafana.com/t/basic-elastic-search-query/1543/4?u=jangaraj

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the great answer by [Jan Garaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3348604/jan-garaj), it looks like there is work being done to make this type of thing much easier in the future.

Check out this [issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/11418) to check progress.